# How to deal with a colleague that doesn't even reply to good morning

Tags: professionalism

I am from a third world country, I have a British colleague that doesn't say anything to me.

He is always good with the others, always replies to their good morning (or good evening, or good weekend), while for me never says more than hi as a reply to good morning when he is alone in the office and I come in the morning so I say good morning

I started monitoring his actions, he absolutely doing this to me, I am not sure if that is because of my nationality.

I have been in the company 5 months and he is 10 years.

How to deal with it? It makes me sad and mad. Should I just ignore it? Should I stop saying anything to him and just say good morning to the others? For example good morning Sandra, if the room has only Sandra and him?

Comment: Is the office in England, your country, or some other location?  Under local norms is it expected to greet every coworker when you arrive to work?

Comment: @Myles the office in the Netherlands, it is not a roll to greet everyone, but everyone answers to the Good morning greetings, except him to me

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Nice proactive idea, thanks. So are you suggesting by keep me saying good morning to him? won't that make me look like a low self steem because I think he is trying to make me not talking with him and I would look like I am desperate to talk with him, right?

Comment: @La Mi He was just afraid (of people). You showed him that is not necessary with you.

Comment: How about "Good morning everyone" or "Good morning colleagues"? Replying to this generic greeting is optional.

Comment: "while for me never says more than hi as a reply to good morning when he is alone in the office" - does this mean he does reply, but you are expecting a full conversation? If this only happens when you are alone in the office there may be other reasons from shyness to worrying he says something that requires a call to HR!

Comment: Consider that there are "valid" reasons on his part to not say hi. Potentially he is very focused on his work and speaking breaks the concentration. Alternatively he doesn't know you and is uncomfortable with greeting random people for no reason.

Answer (score 13):

I'm beginning to feel that this advice would answer a large amount of the questions on here:

> You can't control what other people say or do. 
>   You can only control how you react to it.

combined with

> Do to others as you would have them do to you.

As per Lilienthal's answer, take the high road and treat him as how you would want to be treated yourself.  It's his problem if he doesn't answer back, and I'd like to think that you are not the only one to notice his behavior.

Comment: Peter, I feel the same way, but don't you think that "what people say and do to you" is an extremely important aspect of the workplace? I sure do...implications behind things people say and do inside the workplace are far different than out.

Comment: One important reason to act like this: **You have no idea why he is behaving the way he does**. The moment you start to act based on **your interpretation of** his behavior, you introduce bias, opinion, confusion.

Answer (score 10):

**Take the high road.** While it certainly sounds like this guy has a problem specifically with you, it's a simple truth that in your career you'll run into plenty of people, even colleagues, that you just don't get along with that well. **But the professional thing to do is to remain collegial**: be friendly but distant and treat these people as you would any other random acquaintance.

As long as your work doesn't intersect much with this individual you simply have nothing to gain from trying to force this guy to respond to you when it comes to pleasantries like "Good morning". The fact that he's deliberately singling you out says a lot about him but otherwise shouldn't reflect on you, as long as *you* remain professional. Being petty to this colleague in return may feel like vindication but it just lowers you down to his level and doesn't accomplish much.

I have some reservations about putting the following quote on here because it's so **incredibly NSFW** and profanity-laden, but famous comedian Jim Jefferies made this excellent remark on his latest show:

> Hate doesn’t beat hate. It’s never fucking beat hate. It just makes more hate … the only thing that can beat hate is love. Now, love doesn’t always beat hate, but it does do something. Think about your own personal life. Think about a person who hates you and you hate them. From now on, show that person nothing but love. Now, I’m not saying for a second that the person will start loving you. They’ll probably still fucking hate you. But one thing will happen. **Eventually, everyone will see them as the asshole**. Don’t be the asshole

So just keep greeting this guy when you see him but otherwise keep a professional distance. It may be annoying to willingly subject yourself to a rude non-reply every day, but just imagine how awkward it must be for him or for you other colleagues who see him ignore you for absolutely no reason.

Note that his *only* applies if this person is not in your management chain and his cold behaviour towards you does not impact your work. If either of that is true you would need to address the problem as it could limit your career or performance. In this case it's not your career that's being held back.

It seems possible that your colleague's behaviour is racially motivated but that ultimately doesn't matter, unless it rises to the level of creating a hostile workplace. Ignoring a "hello" typically isn't enough for that.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't be offended by the Britisher's "hi" because I don't use "hi"
 to greet people.

I do say "hi" to everyone but that's my way of announcing that I am in the office. I say "bye" on the way out as my way of announcing that I am leaving the office. So far as I am concerned, I work with everyone and everyone has the right to know when I am on-site and when I am not. Whether people acknowledge my greeting is immaterial to me. Frankly, the Britisher's "hi" is enough for me: he basically acknowledges that I am in the office, which is all I care about. If someone asks him whether I am in the office, he will be able to respond with "I just said 'hi' to him".

Occasionally, I have worked with colleagues I can't stand. In this case, my saying "hi" to them fulfills the additional function of blanking my mind from any negativity I might feel when I see them. I have worked for bosses and with colleagues who were serious head cases. Saying "hi" and "bye" to them was never an issue for me, again because I don't use "hi" and "bye" to be social. The issue that they were head cases was a completely separate matter that I dealt with as a completely separate matter (*)

In summary, I say "hi" and "bye" for my sake not for the sake of others.

(*) A dorm mate taught me an unforgettable object lesson when I was a first-year student at Columbia College of Columbia University. He talked for half an hour on the phone. Couldn't be more courteous, considerate and gracious. Hung up the phone saying "Have a great day!". Then screamed "ASSHOLE!" at the top of his lungs, generating a tsunami sound shock wave that startled the bejesus out of everyone within earshot - that would have been the whole floor plus whoever was in the elevator at that second. If somebody says "hi" or "good morning" or good anything to you with a smile, you have no idea what he might be muttering about you under his breath. A number of times, I have said to the person next to me "You know, the guy I am smiling at and waving at - watch out for him, he's a backstabbing asshole!" I don't read anything, good or bad, into others' greetings. They should know better than read anything including my motivation into mine.